# How do I convert my output to list format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to convert my output as:

```
[5130, 5415, 5700, 5985, 6270, 6555, 6840, 7125, 7410, 7695, 7980]
```

but I only get:

```
5130
5415
5700
5985
6270
6555
6840
7125
7410
7695
7980
```

I have no clue how to convert it. I am inputing the number 15.

my code:

```
x = int(input("Enter your number here: "))

def inrange(x):
  for i in range(5000,8000):
    if i % x ==0 and i % (x +4)==0:
      print(i)
inrange(x)
```

This is the question: Create a program that has a function that takes one integer argument.  The function will print a list of all values between 5000 and 8000 that is divisible by (1) the integer argument, and (2) the argument + 4.

Comment: You are only printing `i`, not building a `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish your function to return a list with your items instead of printing them, try:

```
x = int(input("Enter your number here: "))

    def inrange(x):
      results = []
      for i in range(5000,8000):
        if i % x ==0 and i % (x +4)==0:
          results.append(i)
      return results
inrange(x)
```

Edit:

This attempt was modifying your code so it works. The simplest way as mentioned will be:

```
return [i for i in range(5000,8000) if i % x == 0 and i % (x + 4) == 0]
```

Comment: Or more simply, `return [i for i in range(5000, 8000) if i % x == 0 and i % (x + 4) == 0]`.

Comment: _Technically_, this won't _print_ the list but  simply using `print` vs `return` would solve that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  ` print(i, end='') to make your items print horizontally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).